# Diagonal coordinate grid Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs, coordinates

I am looking to make a coordinate grid with a (darker) diagonal grid (with potentially different grid length) on top of it as in the image below.

I.e I would like to have a tikz image of the coordinate axis transformed by some matrix. Both labeled and unlabeled.

[image]

Comment: Please revise this question showing us the code you've tried so far. This site is not appropriate for "please do this for me" types of questions. To get started, try looking at the `grid` command in `tikz`, along with `rotate`, `xscale`, `yscale` and `\clip`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `scope` and change the axis inside with the coordinate transformation `cm` that allows you to define such transformation as a matrix (see the manual).

For example, this code:

```tex
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-3.5,-3.5) rectangle (3.5,3.5);
% standard grid
\draw[gray] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
% new grid
\begin{scope}[cm={2,-2,  % unit vector, new x axis
                  1,1,   % unit vector, new y axis
                 (0,0)}] % new origin
\draw[magenta] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
% point B(1,1) in the new grid
\node[fill,circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0,label={[right]B}] at (1,1) {};
\end{scope}
% point A(1,1) in the standard grid
\node[fill,circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0,label={[right]A}] at (1,1) {};
% original axes
\draw[thick,-latex] (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0);
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,-3.5) -- (0,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]